# Nested Attributes Unpermitted wit Embedded Mongoid Document via AJAX

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, mongoid5

I am trying to submit a document and an embedded document via Ajax call but keep receiving an "Unpermitted parameter" exception. 
This is my model:

```
class UserForecast
...
  embeds_many :time_entries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :time_entries
...
end
```

My strong parameters:

```
def user_forecast_params
  params.require(:user_forecast).permit(:published, :user_id, :forecast_id, :project_role_id, time_entries_attributes: [:entry_date, :hours])
end
```

The ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/user_forecasts.json' ,
    data : { user_forecast: { user_id: timeEntry.data('user_id'), forecast_id: timeEntry.data('forecast_id'), project_role_id: timeEntry.data('project_role_id'), time_entries: { entry_date: timeEntry.data('date'), hours: timeEntry.value } }},
    type : 'post',
...
```

I cannot see anything that I am missing but yet I receive this in my logs:

```
Unpermitted parameter: time_entries
```

I am using:
Ruby 2.3.0
Rails: 4.2.6
Mongoid: 5.1.5

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out.

first: Obviously, the JSON parameter name needs to be *time_entries_attributes:* and not time_entries.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/user_forecasts.json' ,
    data : { user_forecast: { user_id: timeEntry.data('user_id'), forecast_id: timeEntry.data('forecast_id'), project_role_id: timeEntry.data('project_role_id'), time_entries_attributes: [{ entry_date: timeEntry.data('date'), hours: timeEntry.value }] }},
    type : 'post',
```

once I crossed that bridge, I ran into an *NoMethodError (undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for "2016-11-25":String):
* error which is due to the fact that the time entry value needs to be an array:

```
[{ entry_date: timeEntry.data('date'), hours: timeEntry.value }]
```

This works!